# What is the correct syntax for params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) it is acceptable to key `params` with the `name` you associate with the html values in your template,

*"When the form is submitted, the name will be passed along with the form data, and will make its way to the params hash in the controller with the value entered by the user for that field. For example, if the form contains <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>, then you would be able to get the value of this field in the controller with params[:query]"*

However, when I attempt to access a param I submitted it throws the following error:

[image]

I understand that there are other params besides :name but I am just trying to get this one handled for now before passing the others. I am just making this app to practice the fundamentals.

Also, how come my params are being passed in my URL? These are forms, shouldn't they be submitted as a POST request and thereby able to use strong params with? I think the reason i'm having so much trouble is because I am used to strong params, I am unfamiliar with this syntax. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Order.create(params[:name])
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1> Input information </h1>
<%= form_tag("/order",method: "get") %>
<%= label_tag(:name, "Enter name") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
<%= label_tag(:email, "enter email") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
<h2> Select color </h2>
<%= label_tag(:red,"red") %>
<%= check_box_tag(:red) %>
<%= label_tag(:green,"green") %>
<%= check_box_tag(:green) %>
<%= label_tag(:indigo,"Indigo") %>
<%= check_box_tag(:indigo) %>
<%= submit_tag("submit") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a hash argument to `create`. How will `Order` know that you are setting `name`? You are basically doing this:

`Order.create('phoot')`

You need to specify what `phoot` is:

```
Order.create(name: params[:name])
# ends up being Order.create(name: 'phoot')
```

Comment: Thanks @logan. But how come these params are being passed via the URL instead of through as POST?

Comment: `form_tag("/order",method: "get")` is your problem. You're specifically asking for it to be posted via GET instead of POST.